# Android Realm Module Creation

Tags: android, realm

I need to create Realm module in eclipse IDE.when i tried the example from Realm source.
it throws exception :
caused by io.realm.exceptions.RealmException:could not find io.realm.CreapyAnimalsModuleMediator.

Please suggest How to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like a building issue. Can you please check https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#eclipse to see if there is anything missed? And also try clean the project and build.

Comment: sorry it Throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException "Provided RealmModule must not be null" error.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and build again? And is the proguard enabled?

Comment: I clean and run the project that repeats same. and i have not enable proguard.

Comment: Are you playing with `realmModuleExample`? It might be caused by `@RealmClass` are missing for those Objects in `model`(app and library).